# Router Wi-Fi issues on laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, hardware-failure

To set up the situation, I've been having issues with Wi-Fi on my laptop. The connection slows down and/or stops at irregular intervals, could be minutes could even skip a day.

On the network there are my laptop, a PC connected to the router with an ethernet cable, two TVs with their own adapters and the occasional phone or tablet connected to the Wi-Fi.
I recently changed my ISP and my router and the issue still persists.
New router is TL-WR841ND.

When I run the troubleshooter (Windows 7) or restart the router the issue generally fixes itself.

The PC has no issues whatsoever with internet so I assume the ISP is fine. Devices that are on the Wi-Fi network have the same issue.
Router is brand new.
Laptop driver is up-to-date. (Toshiba Satellite L750-1MX)

I tried my neighbor's network to see if the issue is my laptop but I had zero problems (used it for 3-4 days).

I've checked the PC and the laptop, nothing malicious on either.

I don't expect a definite solve from such a vague description, but any pointers about what I can try would be great.

Comment: Try Hard Reset on the router and do a full reconfiguration of the same. If there is more recent version of Firmware available for router upgrade the same. Try setting a fixed channel frequency in the router settings (if it is set to 'Auto' mode)  and experiment with the same. You can use software like inSSIDer on Windows to see the nearby WiFi networks and their channels. Any nearby cordless phones at the same frequency might be interfering with the router just in case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check power manager, do you allow your OS off your wireless network card to save energy? Deselect it.
2. Check your wireless driver and update it if new stable driver is available.

--------The following is not guaranteed to work--------

3. Install OS updates if available & restart.
4. Try to set your router's channel to 1-10, not auto, as far as I know, some devices cannot use channels above 10 stably.
5. Look at your wifi network connection properties, select QoS and deselect IPv6(if you don't use it), and restart your wifi with offline mode.
6. Try not to broadcast your SSID, and bind your laptop's MAC with an IP addr.